# Real object size measurement using depth image

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I have a depth image along with its RGB image, which have been generated with a stereo camera. I was wondering if it is possible to find the real size of an object (in known metrics like meters or centimeters) which is available in this image? Thanks

find the python code or guidance to map a pixel size into real world size for an object using depth image.

Comment: Please share your images and any details you know about them so we can see what you are referring to. Thank you.